# Applying mask to parent element in CSS, yet with no result

Tags: css, jpeg, mask

I am new to masks and can find very little help online... I've set a mask by making a grayscale JPG and applying it to the parent container. I want everything in that container to be masked according to my JPG's white/black pixels, but after applying the mask, I get no change at all.

Here is the CSS:

```
.site-branding {
position: absolute;
height: 100vh;
width: 100%;
-webkit-mask-image: url('media/masks/catchphrase-mask.jpg');
mask-image: url('media/masks/catchphrase-mask.jpg');
-webkit-mask-size: contain;
mask-size: contain;
-webkit-mask-position: center;
mask-position: center;
}
```

Here is the page: https://satya-ame-art.com/index.php/qui-suis-je/

The idea is that the little character and the animated text should slide up from under the arc. So I need to mask them until they reach the upper half of the screen. Thank you!!!

Comment: mask work only with transparent image, it consider transparent/non-transparent not black/white

Comment: Thank you!! I can't believe I struggled so long with this. I now saved to PNG with transparency and it works.